# Create plot in R, where on each interval the y-axis is a constant line

Tags: r

I have the following matrix

```
intervals = matrix(c( -10.0000000,  -9.9593924,  -8.4761187,  -6.8039396,  -5.9606072,  -3.6667020,  -0.1966284,   0.2648462,   1.0517505,   1.4613391,   2.0021269,  -9.9593924,  -8.4761187,
 -6.8039396,  -5.9606072, -3.6667020,  -0.1966284,   0.2648462,   1.0517505,   1.4613391,   2.0021269,  10.0000000),11,2)
intervals
           [,1]       [,2]
 [1,] -10.0000000 -9.9593924
 [2,]  -9.9593924 -8.4761187
 [3,]  -8.4761187 -6.8039396
 [4,]  -6.8039396 -5.9606072
 [5,]  -5.9606072 -3.6667020
 [6,]  -3.6667020 -0.1966284
 [7,]  -0.1966284  0.2648462
 [8,]   0.2648462  1.0517505
 [9,]   1.0517505  1.4613391
[10,]   1.4613391  2.0021269
[11,]   2.0021269 10.0000000
```

and the following vector

```
V  =c(0.0005169375, 0.0002622374, 0.0009219710, 0.0040686104, 0.0593161201, 0.2037629782, 0.3457855413, 0.0242064392, 0.0070915978, 0.0112686776, 0.3427988894)
```

I would like to ask if there is a nice and efficient way of plotting the intervals on the x-axis and the V on the y-axis in the following way:

Over the interval `(-10,-9.959)` the y axis has to be constant and equal to `0.0005169375`, i.e. for each possible value inside the interval `(-10,-9.959)` the value on the y axis should always be `0.0005169375`, whereas on the interval `(-9.959,-8.476)` the y axis should be equal to `0.0002622374` for every possible value inside the interval ```(-9.959,-8.476). In a few words I want to create the following plot (displayed here for only the first three intervals) calculated in a more efficient way, and instead of point lines.

```
plot(c(seq(-10,-9.95,length=10),seq(-9.95,-8.4761,length=10),seq(-8.4761,-6.8039,length=10)),c(rep(V[1],10),rep(V[2],10),rep(V[3],10)))
```

Comment: I think you might need to specify what is meant by "the y-axis should be constant on an interval". The words sound internally contradictory to me.

Comment: @IRTFM thanks you, i'm adding more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for a step plot.

```
plot(x=intervals[,1], y=V, type="s")
```

You may need to adjust the first column of intervals[,1] to plot the entire range.

[image]

**Update**
To handle the final interval, you need to create a new X and Y vectors to handle the last value.

```
xvalues <- c(intervals[,1], intervals[nrow(intervals), 2])
yvalue <- c(V, V[length(V)])

plot(x=xvalues, y=yvalue, type="s")
```

Comment: I think this might be it - otherwise if OP doesn't want the vertical joins, `segments` might be able to do it: `plot(NA, xlim=range(intervals), ylim=range(V)); apply(cbind(intervals, V), 1, \(x) segments(x0=x[1], x1=x[2], y0=x[3]) )`

Comment: @Dave2e Thanks for your reply. The problem is that your plot doesn't display the interval ```(2,10)```

Comment: @Jonathan1234, see the update above